# NaturalDoc problem while generating documentation for VBA module

Tags: vba, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, code-documentation

I hope you're doing well

I am working with NaturalDoc version 2.1.1, to generate documentation for VBA Module

The problem is when I use accented character in VBA comments, the result is some wierd character, like question mark in black small lozenge

I think the problem is in encoding, between VBA module (having the extension .bas) and NaturalDoc

How can I fix the problem ?

Comment: Why not ask this question here - https://www.reddit.com/r/NaturalDocs/   ?

Comment: I see the likn you sent to me, and I try to follow a similar issus here https://github.com/NaturalDocs/NaturalDocs/issues/68
But when I follow this, I get an error telling that the keywork "Encoding" does not exist